# Dependency 'org.openpnp:opencv-face:4.5.4-1' not found

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, opencv

I am new to spring boot. Here I am trying to get

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openpnp</groupId>
            <artifactId>opencv-face</artifactId>
            <version>4.5.4-1</version>
            <classifier>windows-x86_64</classifier>
        </dependency>
```

But I am getting this error:- Dependency 'org.openpnp:opencv-face:4.5.4-1' not found

Here is my pom.xml code-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.2</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.square</groupId>
    <artifactId>square</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>square</name>
    <description>square</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>openpnp-releases</id>
            <url>https://repo.openpnp.org/release/</url>
        </repository>

        <repository>
            <id>opencv-releases</id>
            <url>https://repo.opencv.org/maven2/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openpnp</groupId>
            <artifactId>opencv</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.2-1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openpnp</groupId>
            <artifactId>opencv</artifactId>
            <version>4.5.3-1</version>
            <classifier>windows-x86_64</classifier>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openpnp</groupId>
            <artifactId>opencv-face</artifactId>
            <version>4.5.4-1</version>
            <classifier>windows-x86_64</classifier>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.firebase</groupId>
            <artifactId>firebase-admin</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

I don't know where is the problem in the pom.xml file. I have tried every possible way I know to solve this problem but I am unble to get it done. Someone please help me.

Comment: have you tried `mvn clean package` ? - If so, what's the output?

Comment: Failed to connect dependencies at org.openpnp:opencv-face:jar:windows-x86_64:4.5.4-1:

Comment: you asked this again: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75425201/how-to-compare-two-faces-in-springboot-using-opencv

Answer (score 2):

The artifact isn't in maven central? As far as I can tell, the response from maven is correct.

https://search.maven.org/search?q=org.openpnp

https://mvnrepository.com/search?q=org.openpnp

The DNS name `repo.openpnp.org` doesn't exist according to my DNS resolver. So I looked in maven central. Without even being able to see the repository, is the question even really valid?

Does the dependency you are trying to use even exist anymore?

Comment: OP is using a different repository for that library

Comment: The DNS name `repo.openpnp.org` doesn't exist according to my DNS resolver. So I looked in maven central. Without even being able to see the repository, is the question even really valid?

Comment: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.openpnp/opencv

Comment: It isn't just the repository, there is no `opencv-face` artifact in Maven central.

Comment: ah, I see... I missed that part... so the answer is to remove the dependency as it no longer exists

Comment: I even think that it might be the wrong org and that this is what he is looking for (facial recognition?) https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.opencv

See: https://opencv.org/opencv-face-recognition/

Comment: You might be correct... should add it to your answer ;)

Comment: I am new to this can you tell me the changes required

Comment: context: openPNP is a software application that lets you control a pick-and-place machine for PCB assembly. it uses OpenCV for automated visual parts placement. perhaps the OpenPNP people decided to provide and maintain builds of OpenCV. perhaps they stopped. I am unaware of official OpenCV builds for java, no matter the build system (or whatever maven can be described as).